# DataGridView column format

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

There is my reading to DGV

```
public void ReadFromDB()
{
    dataset = DB.ReadFromDB("SELECT * FROM orders");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];

    //another columns....

    DataGridViewColumn sellDate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    sellDate.DataPropertyName = "sell_date";
    sellDate.ReadOnly = true;
    sellDate.Name = "Дата продажи";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(sellDate);
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 80;
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

Why formatting doesn't work?
DefaultCellStyle.Format is set:

[image: screen]

Comment: Columns[4] means the 5th column, the index is started from 0. make sure the 5th column is DateTime type.

Comment: I know this, column number is fine

Answer (score 3):

just in case if someone is looking for the answer to this question...

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy";
```

all you have to do is add single quotations before and after the slash like this '/'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the column index is [4] or [5]. You can check it from designer also.

Also make sure that the column is of DateTime type then only it will be get formatted.

Comment: Where i can check column type? I think the type is       DataGridViewColumn sellDate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
In MySQL database tupe is date.

Answer (score 0):

If your getting this from the database, its getting the format from your table.

Comment: Yes, but Formatting should change format to another? Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it may be the slash/backslash issue. Try this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd\\/MM\\/yyyy";
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"dd\/MM\/yyyy";
```