# DateTime convert to shortdatetime in grid

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-entities

How can I convert the selected dates to shortdate types in my grid? I only wanna show the dates and not time.

```
vasketidssystemEntities forbindelse = new vasketidssystemEntities();

    public OwnReservations()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            ObjectQuery<reservation> reservationer = forbindelse.reservations;

            var query =
            from res in reservationer
            where res.resident_ID == 17
            orderby res.date
            select new { res.date, res.hourofday, res.resident_ID };

           datagrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the column format for that column you want to format, like so:

```
datagrid1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```

Do this after you have set the ItemsSource of the datagrid1.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270212/c-sharp-datagridview-column-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the answer found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370402/entity-framework-4-linq-how-to-convert-from-datetime-to-string-in-a-query), namely:

```
reservationer.Select(a => new { a.date, a.hourofday, a.resident_ID })
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(p => new 
                                { date = p.date.ToShortDateString(),
                                  hourofday = p.hourofday,
                                  resident_ID = p.resident_ID
                                });
```